# Correct pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling

Is the correct pronunciation of an English word mutable according to popular usage? I don’t want to mispronounce words the way I hear them used because people ignore the correct spelling ie ibuprofen vs Ibeeprofen.

Comment: Push the "play" buttons: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/mutable

Comment: And "ibuprofen" is pronounced pretty much the way it is spelled.

Comment: I have never, ever, ever, ever, ever heard anyone pronounce "ibuprofen" as "ibeeprofen."

Comment: The standard pronunciation of the second syllable is "byoo", and the link by @HotLicks gives both US and UK pronunciations of the whole word; see [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ibuprofen) and [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ibuprofen) for other examples of pronunciation. Yes, the "standard" can change either at a regional level or more widely over time but there's nothing wrong with sticking to the "correct" pronunciation.

Comment: If someone said "ibeeprofen" to me, I'd probably say back, "*'Ibeeprofen'?* You be illin'."

Comment: *"because people ignore the correct spelling"* - Note that in English, spelling does not determine pronunciation.

Comment: @nnnnnn -- Yes, English is unlike, say, Spanish, where the "official" spelling of a word may actually be changed because the pronunciation has changed.

Comment: Notice the example given in the answers. In all cases the first vowel is said very quickly. It is very difficult to distinguish vowels sounds when said quickly, and since English pronunciations vary by region and accent of the talker, the task is even harder. Use the cheat the examples give and simply say the vowel quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the "correct" pronunciation of an English word does not exist. English, like most languages has accents and dialects and pronunciation of words will vary from place to place.

Answer (score 1):

Just to chime in:
I'm from the American south and this is the only way we pronounce Ibuprofen down here that I have heard my entire life--
"i-bee-pro-fen".

I've even heard non-regional tv commercials say it like that so it's not something just limited to my geographical area.
Strange but true!

Here's a couple examples: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2B5VAGcsKcE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwmfQeFznzs

Comment: The pronunciations in the first link are a hair garbled, but are closer to "eye-byou-profen" than "eye-bee-profen.  The second link is definitely "eye-byou-profen".  Often people hear what they're used to hearing, vs what is actually pronounced.